# windows phone 8 app testing

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am a developer of windows phone 7. Now i am shifting to windows phone 8. But when i installed windows  phone 8 sdk. I come to know that wp8 emulator requires special hardware features. Unfortunality my PC is a little outdated, means i didn't to supports this emulator. And also buying a new windows phone 8 is not possible for me. SO i was looking is there any online app running facility available so i can test my apps or is there any way to run emulator in my laptop. Kindly help me out in this matter .Thanks
my laptop
compaq presario cq61. intel core2duo 2.1 Ghz, 3GB of RAM.

Comment: If it helps, you could pay to get into the Nokia Developer Program and use their Remote Device Access, which lets you interact with a real device over the internet. But you'd be halfway to owning a cheap WP8 device at that point. http://www.developer.nokia.com/Devices/Remote_device_access/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of the requirements to run the Windows Phone 8 Emulator. It doesn't look like your laptop specs meet the exact criteria but as long as your BIOS supports virtualization, SLAT, and DEP (mentioned in the article) - you might be able to run it (although you'd probably see poor performance).

As for an online testing facility, which would presumably be running the emulator on a different server, I don't know of anything that exists like that.

Also note that even without the Emulator, you should still be able to install the SDK, and as long as you're running Visual Studio 2012, you'll be able to deploy your app to your WP8 device for testing (assuming you're eventually able to buy a WP8 device).

Hope this helps.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524(v=vs.105).aspx